# Odd MongoDB/Node Explain Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm trying to figure this out... any help would be awesome.

I have identical queries that I'm running in RoboMongo (CLI):

```
db.post.find({utc:{$lte:utc}})
.sort({utc:-1}).limit(100).hint({utc:-1})
```

and my Node app (using the Native driver):

```
mo.post.find({utc:{$lte:utc}},{
  fields:{geo:0, bin:0, flg:0, mod:0, edt:0},
  hint:{utc:-1}, sort:{utc:-1}, limit:100
}).toArray(function(err, result)
```

For some reason, the performance is crazy different. The top one runs in under 1ms, the bottom takes over 100ms. When I review the 'explain' for the fast one I get:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor utc_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 100,
    "nscanned" : 100,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 100,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 100,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "utc" : [ 
            [ 
                ISODate("2015-01-07T00:47:32.786Z"), 
                true
            ]
        ]
    },
```

and for the slow one:

```
cursor: "BtreeCursor utc_-1"
isMultiKey: false
n: 1
nscannedObjects: 1
nscanned: 1
nscannedObjectsAllPlans: 1
nscannedAllPlans: 1
scanAndOrder: false
indexOnly: false
nYields: 0
nChunkSkips: 0
millis: 0
indexBounds: {
utc: [1]
0:  [2]
0:  "2015-01-07T22:50:05.000Z"
1:  true
-
-
}-
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here? They are running off the same database with the same indexes?

Comment: They can't be explains for the same query - the same query should produce the same `n` if they have the same value of limit+skip. Can you double check that you have got the explains for the right queries? Also, where is the timing info coming from?

Comment: That's the odd thing - it's the exact same query - and it produces the same result. The N=1 explain makes no sense, and that's the query taking forever. Both hit the same table, and timing is from RoboMongo (on fast query) and HTTP client calling local host on slower query (run via native node driver).

Comment: I'm also seeing screwy behavior here: different but maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831936/limit-1-1ms-limit-1-150ms-mongo-melt-down

Comment: Can you run the query in the mongo shell and post an explain? I am suspicious of RoboMongo but I also don't know much about it.

Comment: It's the same as RoboMongo. The problem seems to be the native driver explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844128/mongodb-native-node-driver-explain-is-broken

Answer (score 0):

Update: seems to be a 2.0.x problem...

I just ran the exact same query with 2.0.x and 1.4.x. When Limit = 1, both perform fast ~1ms. When Limit = 2, the 1.4.x version stays around 1ms but the 2.0.x version jumps to 25ms. So, it's not just an issue with the explain output - that's just a symptom of the problem.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 9:04:05 AM UTC-8, Joshua Abrams wrote:
Interesting... exact same query using 1.4.x yields a proper explain where n = 2 (and so on). Could this be affecting performance? When I run a query where Limit = 1 it's fast (as expected) but when Limit = 2 it's 100x slower...

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 8:52:28 AM UTC-8, christkv wrote:
not really. My suggestion is to make a minimal reproducible test case (code and data) and open a ticket on jira.mongodb.com. kind of hard to know what could be happening. it's unlikely to be the driver but one never knows. try with the 1.4.x branch aswell just to at least rule out that it's a 2.0.x branch issue.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 5:47:45 PM UTC+1, Joshua Abrams wrote:
Just checked and I'm using 2.0.12 of the driver. Any other thoughts?

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 8:23:16 AM UTC-8, christkv wrote:
explain is just retuning all the results in the driver instead of partial results. thus you get the plan. One thing that comes to mind might be that you are on a driver earlier than 1.4.19 that had an error where batchSize was set to 1.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 5:01:42 PM UTC+1, Joshua Abrams wrote:
I've been having a suite of performance issues lately with the driver.
[Limit = 1 = 1ms, Limit > 1 = 150ms (mongo-melt-down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831936/limit-1-1ms-limit-1-150ms-mongo-melt-down)

Not sure what the root cause it - and it's impossible to debug when I can't get a proper explain:
[MongoDB Native Node Driver: Explain is Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844128/mongodb-native-node-driver-explain-is-broken)