# Limit = 1 = 1ms, Limit > 1 = 150ms (mongo-melt-down)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

Using MongoDB Native Driver, here's the query:

```
  mo.post.find({_us:_us, utc:{$lte:utc}},{
    fields:{geo:0, bin:0, flg:0, mod:0, edt:0},
    hint:{_us:1, utc:-1},
    sort:{utc:-1},
    limit:X,
    explain:true
  }).toArray(function(err, result){
    if (err) {res.status(500).send(err);}
    else if (result.length > 0){res.status(200).json(result);}
    else {res.status(204).send();}
  });
```

When X (the limit) is 1, the response time is ~1ms. When I set it to 2, the response time jumps to +150ms. Huh...? The explain for both queries are identical:

```
cursor: "BtreeCursor _us_1_utc_-1"
isMultiKey: false
n: 1
nscannedObjects: 1
nscanned: 1
nscannedObjectsAllPlans: 1
nscannedAllPlans: 1
scanAndOrder: false
indexOnly: false
nYields: 0
nChunkSkips: 0
millis: 0
indexBounds: {
_us: [1]
0:  [2]
0:  "54add9321656d4a9fa760b24"
1:  "54add9321656d4a9fa760b24"
-
-
utc: [1]
0:  [2]
0:  "2015-01-08T02:15:29.429Z"
1:  true
```

Yes, they both just show 1 scanned object? Is my index broken? Even when I increase the limit to X = 100, the response time stays pretty much the same as X = 2, and the explain is identical, just showing 1 scanned object. I have no idea what's going on...? These exact queries when run in RoboMongo take under 1ms. So, might it be the driver? or toArray?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the 2.0.x driver: here's a thread...

I just ran the exact same query with 2.0.x and 1.4.x. When Limit = 1, both perform fast ~1ms. When Limit = 2, the 1.4.x version stays around 1ms but the 2.0.x version jumps to 25ms. So, it's not just an issue with the explain output - that's just a symptom of the problem.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 9:04:05 AM UTC-8, Joshua Abrams wrote:
Interesting... exact same query using 1.4.x yields a proper explain where n = 2 (and so on). Could this be affecting performance? When I run a query where Limit = 1 it's fast (as expected) but when Limit = 2 it's 100x slower...

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 8:52:28 AM UTC-8, christkv wrote:
not really. My suggestion is to make a minimal reproducible test case (code and data) and open a ticket on jira.mongodb.com. kind of hard to know what could be happening. it's unlikely to be the driver but one never knows. try with the 1.4.x branch aswell just to at least rule out that it's a 2.0.x branch issue.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 5:47:45 PM UTC+1, Joshua Abrams wrote:
Just checked and I'm using 2.0.12 of the driver. Any other thoughts?

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 8:23:16 AM UTC-8, christkv wrote:
explain is just retuning all the results in the driver instead of partial results. thus you get the plan. One thing that comes to mind might be that you are on a driver earlier than 1.4.19 that had an error where batchSize was set to 1.

On Thursday, January 8, 2015 5:01:42 PM UTC+1, Joshua Abrams wrote:
I've been having a suite of performance issues lately with the driver.
[Limit = 1 = 1ms, Limit > 1 = 150ms (mongo-melt-down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831936/limit-1-1ms-limit-1-150ms-mongo-melt-down)

Not sure what the root cause it - and it's impossible to debug when I can't get a proper explain:
[MongoDB Native Node Driver: Explain is Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844128/mongodb-native-node-driver-explain-is-broken)